# Optional Argument for Custom Activities in Workflow Foundation

Tags: c#, android-activity, workflow-foundation-4, workflow-activity

Is there a way to have an optional argument for a custom activity within Workflow Designer in C#, .NET environment.  I know that for Required Arguments here is the syntax:

```
[RequiredArgument]
[Description("The status to query.")]
public InArgument<StatusValues> Status { get; set; }
```

But I am wondering how do I define an input argument that could be optional?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Take off the RequiredArgument attribute.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, the default for all arguments is to be optional. So, without the [RequiredArgument] attribute, your argument is optional without anything else you must do.

(I hope I did not miss your point, as this seems to be so obvious...?)

Comment: I found that out after posting the question.